RestTemplate, RestClient VS WebClient
I have a Spring web application which does Http calls to external web services, for now it uses WebClient from webflux for making such calls, but everytime it uses .block() since we don't need asynchronous proccessing
    public <T> T sendGetRequest(Class<T> responseType, URI uri) {
        return webClient.get().uri(uri)
                .headers(WebRequestUtil::setHeaders)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(responseType)
                .block();
    }

So, the question is, since there are no async programming, isn't it better to use WebClient, or it is ok to use WebClient with .block()
I dont want to do micro optimizations, should I do refactoring ?

If you keep the WebClient, you can be non-blocking if you ever want to, or continuing to block as you currently do. It opens up a choice at the expense of one line of code (block), so, I don’t see any reason to use a RestTemplate.
P.S.: Your question sounds like one that was posed in a code review. Nothing wrong with that though.
